# Error only present when using Django Nose test runner: View must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include()

Tags: python, django, django-nose

All of my tests run as expected when I use Django's default test runner. When I add `TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'` to my project's settings, I receive a `TypeError` that states `view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().`

I'm using Django version 2.1.5—and don't really have any idea where to start debugging this error. In this case the *only* difference between my tests running and throwing an error is the inclusion of the above line into my `settings.py` file.

Has anyone run into this problem before? I'm getting it with all of my views.

My main `mysite/urls.py` paths look like this (as per Django's documentation):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('sound/', include('sound.urls')),
]
```

Which, just to see if it'd do anything, I changed to:

```
from sound import urls as sound_urls
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('soundtests/', sound_urls),
]
```

But this did not change the error at all.

---

This is *not* a duplicate of any of the other questions with this error. This problem **only** occurs when I use `django_nose` as my test runner. I am not referencing my views with strings in any of my `urls.py` files.

**Edit:** I do *not* get the same error simply running `coverage run manage.py test` using Django's default test runner.

Comment: Which version of nose are you using? (Use e.g. `pip freeze` find out).

Comment: @trixn `pip freeze | grep nose` shows `django-nose==1.4.6` and `nose==1.3.7`. These seem to be the most recent versions.